# Image optimization tools?

Tags: untagged

I'm trying to do research on finding a good jpeg and gif optimizer for linux command but the ones I'm finding date back to 2001 which *may* be good but it's hard to believe there have been no advanced in the last 8 years.

Do you know of any good performing jpeg and gif optimizers?

Answer (score 1):

Just because it's old doesn't mean it's not any good.  ;)  Not much has changed with image formats over the past few years either.  Have you checked out [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)?

Comment: Yea I've tried ImageMagick but I'm having troubles with it's PHP addon and actually getting it to compress.